# Asynchronous curl causes server to freeze sometimes

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing asynchronous curl requests on a multi-dimensional array of URLs.

I want to do blocking so that subsequent code won't execute before finishing downloading all the results, but sometimes this causes the server to lock up and I can't even SSH into the machine, so I have to restart the machine.

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$aCurlHandles = array(array());
foreach($a_urls as $key => $inner_array){
foreach($inner_array as $inner_key => $jsonresult){
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $a_urls[$key][$inner_key]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $aCurlHandles[$key][$inner_key] = $ch;
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);
    }
}
$active = null;
do{
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
}while($mrc === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active); // ********* added "|| $active"
while($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK){
    if(curl_multi_select($mh) != -1){
        do{
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        }while($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
$a_results = array(array());
foreach($aCurlHandles as $key => $inner_array){
    foreach($inner_array as $inner_key => $ch){
     $response = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
     $jsonresult = json_decode($response);
     $a_results[$key][$inner_key] = $jsonresult;
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    }
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

When it doesn't lock up the machine it works fine and receives all the data correctly, so the code is mostly working, but I guess there is something like a memory leak.

I'm not sure what the problem is, but the line with `*********` is non-standard, and was the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
// execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while ($running);
```

as per the comment in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

The CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM example shown in the manual isn't reliable in my experience.

Comment: For both lines? I used CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM twice

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Only need 1 loop, not two.

Comment: CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM stopped getting returned in curl version 7.20.0 - a very long time ago... [as documented](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html)